# Zend\Sql\TableGateway|Where|Predicate does not replace the string in the where condition - Is this a bug?

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework2

I put together a small application using Zf2 based on the tutorial and where I would like to get data from the database I had to face a strange issue.

I have this method in my TableGateway class:

```php
public function selectWith($select = null) {

    $filter = new Predicate();
    $filter->like('category_name',"%dess%")
            ->OR
            ->like('category_desc', "%ks%");

    var_dump($this->tableGateway->select(function(Select $select) use ($filter) {
        $select->where($filter);
    }));

    return $this->tableGateway->select(function(Select $select) use ($filter) {
        $select->where($filter);
    });
}
```

According to the dump the following query was executed:

```sql
SELECT `categories`.* FROM `categories` WHERE (`category_name` LIKE :where1 OR `category_desc` LIKE :where2)
```

Instead of this which should be formalized by the source code:

```sql
SELECT `categories`.* FROM `categories` WHERE (`category_name` LIKE '%dess%' OR `category_desc` LIKE '%ks%')
```

Is this a bug, or did I wrong something?

According to the [API](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.2/classes/Zend.Db.Sql.Predicate.Like.html) the Like accepts only two parameters, both are string.

I use ZF 2.2.2

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
No, this is not a bug. Please check below how it works:<br />
```

Before viewing the vardump of select statement

```
var_dump($this->tableGateway->select(function(Select $select) use ($filter) {
    $select->where($filter);
}));

Please perform the var_dump of $filter. Where you will find the array of like statements.

example:

["predicates":protected]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(3) "AND"
      [1]=>
      object(Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Like)#377 (3) {
        ["specification":protected]=>
        string(14) "%1$s LIKE %2$s"
        ["identifier":protected]=>
        string(12) "contact_name"
        ["like":protected]=>
        string(4) "%dess%"
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(2) "OR"
      [1]=>
      object(Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Like)#378 (3) {
        ["specification":protected]=>
        string(14) "%1$s LIKE %2$s"
        ["identifier":protected]=>
        string(13) "business_name"
        ["like":protected]=>
        string(4) "%ks%"
      }
    }
  }
}


These two array's ["like":protected] portion are replaced with "where1" and "where2" respectively when the query is being executed. <br />
Thanks :)
```